# How can I set the image quality in a google drive api export for a google docs in python?

Tags: python, pdf, google-drive-api

I am using python and the recommended google drive api to generate and create new documents.
However, the image qualtiy in the resulting pdf document is quite low.

How can i set a better image quality?

Code:

```
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    file_id = real_file_id

    # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
    request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                           mimeType='application/pdf')
    file = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print(F'Download {int(status.progress() * 100)}.')
```

from here: [Download a Google Workspace Document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads)

Comment: Have you tried doing this though the web app?  Are you sure this is an issue with the api and not just an issue with drive in genral?

Comment: Beyond that i cant see any way to tweek the settings on export. I would bug report it and see what google says https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B

Comment: Hi, can you provide a sample pdf document in order to test this?

Comment: It seems like the issue is not an api one, but also when using the export on the website.

Comment: Here is an example: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UFCJUmoyI2lAmenAiair-YstyLF38dpdWCmCU6K4_Do/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I filed the Issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238350796

Comment: Hi, since this is not an API issue (it's how Drive in general seems to be working at this point), it should be reported via `Send feedback`. That's what Google responded: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238350796#comment2